# Reputation flair not the same as reputation flair on the side-bar of area-51, is this a glitch?

Tags: support, bug, area-51

My rep flair doesn't seem to be the same as in my *About me* section as it would be on the side panel of recent followers in [area-51, shown here.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40380/malware)

*About me*

[image]

Side-bar of recent followers:

[image]

It doesn't seem to be taking account of bounty I had at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/users/106729/foxtrot?tab=reputation).  Is this normal?  I asked about this in chat but it did not resolve the quandary.

Comment: How long has it been since you offered the boundary? Is caching a reasonable explanation?

Comment: Caching locally? Im on a computer which I haven't been on any Stack exchange sites till now.  I offered the bounty April 19th per the link and rep change.  (-50)

Answer (score 2):

Rep shown on the SE flair does not include Area51, whereas Area51 's flair includes itself. Sites with rep < 200 are always excluded. Anything else, blame caching.

Comment: If you hover over the Server Fault icon in the side-bar, it says that he still has 203 reputation there. It's clearly not updated.